# AWS CodePipeline permission error on Release change action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have started getting the following error recently on release change action int eh AWS codePipeline console. Also attaching the screenshot

> Action execution failed
>
> Insufficient permissions The provided role does not have permissions
>   to perform this action. Underlying error: Access Denied (Service:
>   Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID:
>   CA26EF93E3DAF8F0; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   mKkobqLGbj4uco8h9wDOBjPeWrRA2ybCrEsVoSq/MA4IFZqJb6QJSrlNrKk/EQK40TfLbTbqFuQ=)

I can't find any resources online anywhere for this error code.

[image: AWS CodePipeline Error]

Answer (score 4):

Your pipeline is trying to access a S3 bucket, but AWS CodePipeline ServiceRole does not have permission to access it. Create an IAM policy that provides access to S3 and attach it to the CodePipeline service role.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jeevagan said, you must create a new IAM Policy that grant access to the Pipeline Buckets.

Do not forget to add the following actions:

```
         Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
          - "s3:List*"
          - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
```

I lost a few minutes because of this one in particular: **GetObjectVersion**

By checking your codedeploy-output, you'll be able to see that the process is downloading a particular version of your artefact with the parameter "versionId".

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the **GetBucketVersioning** action in your policy, so the correct example looks like below. I don't know why it's not mentioned anywhere in the reference/documentation:

```
- PolicyName: AccessRequiredByPipeline
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: !Sub ${YouBucket.Arn}/* 
              - Action:
                  - s3:GetBucketVersioning
                Resource: !Sub ${YouBucket.Arn}
                Effect: Allow
              - Action:
                  - kms:GenerateDataKey
                  - kms:Decrypt
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: !GetAtt KMSKey.Arn
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potential culprit that mascarades behind this error that references S3 is missing KMS permissions on the IAM Role for the CodePipeline.  If you configured your CodePipeline to use KMS encryption, then the service role used/associated with the CodePipeline will also need KMS permissions to that KMS key in order to interact with the KMS encrypted objects in S3.  In my experience, the missing KMS permissions will cause the same error message to appear which references S3.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, but the permissions were all set properly - I used the same CloudFormation template with other projects no problem. It turned out that the key name I was using in the S3 bucket was too long. Apparently it doesn't like anything more than 20 characters. Once I changed the key name in my S3 bucket (and all of its associated references in the CloudFormation template files), everything worked properly

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue when I used cloud formation to build my CI/CD, my problem was the CodePipeline ArtifactStore pointed to the wrong location in the S3 ("codepipeline" a not allowed access folder in my case). Changing the ArtifactStore to an existing folder fixed my issue.

You can view pipeline details like where the SourceArtifact is pointed by following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-view-console.html#pipelines-list-console)